# "You have X flags remaining."

Tags: support

I just flagged a question because I wasn't sure whether it was too localized or a discussion question or what have you — it just didn't smell right to me. I got the message that I had something like 11 flags remaining.

So what happens when I get to the end of those flags? I can't get mod attention anymore? They reset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomorrow you should have 12 flags again.

Quoting [Shog9's answer in meta.so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890/171926):

> You start with **10 flags per day**.
>
> Based on your reputation and flagging history, you can end up with as
>   many as 100 per day.
>
> Since you have an insane number of helpful flags, you're maxed out at
>   100 per day.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know it was "per day." Thanks!